# Why ExtractMultiValuesToPoints not working for Point file?

Tags: arcpy, extract, multi-values, null

I'm struggling to extract depths from a bathymetry raster to a Point file with multiple features (not Multipoint, as I previously mis-stated). In trying to use `ExtractMultiValuesToPoints()`, I noticed it worked on feature classes with one point, but not those with multiple points. Here's an example I've run on two test files.

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.sa as SA

bathy = [filepath]
testgrid1 = [filepath] (one point)
testgrid4 = [filepath] (four points)

SA.ExtractMultiValuesToPoints(testgrid1, [[bathy, "depth"]], "BILINEAR")
SA.ExtractMultiValuesToPoints(testgrid4, [[bathy, "depth"]], "BILINEAR")
```

Results: "depth" columns are added to both files. The correct depth inserted into the depth column of 'testgrid1'; but  values are inserted into the depth column of 'testgrid4'.

I'm certain that there's data in the bathymetry file at the location of the points, so I can't fathom why this isn't working.

Comment: Is your input points a multipoint feature class? The help http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000002s000000 says *Multipoint datasets are not supported as input* convert your multipoint to points using MultipartToSinglepart http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003r000000 before using as an input.

Comment: What imports and definitions relevant to the code that you have presented have been performed?  They need to be included for this to be a code snippet that works up to where you are stuck.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson: Well, thank you - that seems cut and dry! Given that, `ExtractMultiValuesToPoints` is certainly a misleading name... it should be `...ToPoint`. I previously accomplished this task, but now knowing this important limitation I must have run the above tool inside my loop function to fully populate the 'depth' column. Is there really no built-in way to add depths to multiple points?

Comment: @joechoj ExtractMultIValuesToPoints is correct, as it is extracting them to more than one point, just the dataset isn't a MultiPoint dataset (where you can have multiple points representing a *single* feature).

Comment: @Midavalo: It seems I've been using terms loosely that I don't fully understand. I simply meant to say my file is a 'Point' file, which contains multiple points. I wasn't aware there was a separate geometry called Multipoint. I've checked my feature class properties, and the geometry is listed as Point. Would a multipoint file list its geometry as 'Multipoint'? Or does simply having more than one point make it a 'Multipoint' file by definition?

Comment: @joechoj No, a Point feature class and a MultiPoint feature class are two different types.  A Point feature class will hold points (can be multiple points) where each individual point represents a single record.  A MultiPoint feature class holds points where each record may be represented by a multiple point locations.  If you ID a Multipoint it will highlight all the points that make up that single record.  See [Creating a multipoint feature](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-a-multipoint-feature.htm)

Comment: @joechoj From your comment though, it sounds like your question may still not be answered?  If you weren't actually referring to Multipoint Feature Class, but rather a point feature class with multiple points, then it may be worth an [edit] to your question to clarify the problem and maybe a bit more information about what you've tried and what exactly isn't working.  Have you tried using the tool directly from ArcToolbox within ArcMap (rather than just through python)?

Comment: @joechoj I have updated my answer with more info.

Answer (score 2):

Multipoint datasets are not supported by the *Extract Multi Values to Points* tool.  See [Extract Multi Values to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-multi-values-to-points.htm#ESRI_USAGES_7C07D60E01874E7399D0C80F9304B197) ArcGIS Docmentation, second to last point under *Usage*:

> ### Usage
>
> *Caution: This tool modifies the input data. Consider making a duplicate copy of the dataset first and execute the tool on that, instead. Alternatively, if the results aren't satisfactory, you can remove the added fields with the Delete Field tool.*
>
> - Any combination of rasters (single band or multiband) can be specified as input.
> - A cell value will be extracted for each input raster and a new field containing the cell values for each input raster are appended to the
>     input point feature class.
> - Output field names are created from the name of the input raster by default; otherwise, you can specify a unique name for each field to
>     store raster values.
> - When the input is a multiband raster, a field will be added for all bands with a b1_, b2_, …bn prefix added to the name of the output
>     field denoting the band number.
> - The interpolation option determines how the values will be obtained from the raster. The default option is to use the value at the center
>     of the cell being sampled. The interpolation option will use bilinear
>     interpolation to interpolate a value for the cell center.
> - Shapefile formats have a maximum field limitation of 10 characters in length. Output fields appended to the input shapefile will be
>     truncated and made unique by default. This may make it hard to
>     distinguish between input rasters if the names are long or very
>     similar. In this case it is suggested to convert the input features to
>     a file geodatabase and use those as the input instead.
> - NoData cells in the value raster will be given a NULL Value. For shapefiles, NULL is not supported and a value of 0 (zero) will be
>     given.
> - **Multipoint datasets are not supported as input.**
> - See Analysis environments and Spatial Analyst for additional details on the geoprocessing environments that apply to this tool.

---

In response to your comments, I have run a test using the Extract Multi Values to Points tool.

1. I created 4 polygon feature classes and a point feature class
2. Added a number of polygons and random values to each polygon feature class
3. Converted Polygon to Raster so I now have 4 rasters with cells containing the random values.

   [image]
4. Created a point feature class, and randomly added a number of points all over my data view (most over the rasters, some not)

   [image]
5. Ran the Extract Multi Values to Points tool

   [image]
6. Viewed the attribute table of my point feature class to verify the values from my rasters had been transferred to my points

   [image]

So I can confirm that the *Extract Multi Values to Points* tool does indeed take the values from rasters and add them to multiple points in a point feature class.  The "Multi" in the tool name comes from the fact it draws values from multiple raster inputs.